# When does a foreign transaction fee apply to a credit card (especially from shopping online)?

Tags: credit-card, canada, foreign-currency, online-shopping

I assume if you go to another country and use a credit card, then the foreign transaction fee will always apply.

What if I use a credit card to make a purchase from an online store? Does it depend on if they say the charges are in CAD or another currency? This can be rather unfortunate as not all sites make clear if the prices are in CAD or USD. In the US and Canada are there laws that require online stores to specify what the currency is? For example I notice on Amazon.ca and Amazon.com neither state CAD or USD (though ending in .ca probably implies Canadian currency).

Comment: What 'Foreign Transaction Fee' are you talking about? Do you mean the conversion rate to get into CAD? Or some additional surcharge?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Many cards in the US apply a foreign transaction fee of 1% or so (I've seen as high as 3%) if the merchant is outside of the USA. On top of whatever spread they take on the conversion rate. https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/credit-cards/foreign-transaction-fee

Comment: @ceejayoz I believe that's mainly (only?) in the US, for other countries the foreign transaction fee is essentially baked into the exchange rate used.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon for example the American Express " Foreign Transaction Fee: 2.7% of each transaction after conversion to US dollars" https://www.americanexpress.com/us/business/credit-cards/simplycash-plus-vs-blue-business-cash/

Comment: When: whenever they can get away with it.  Why: Because they can.